# Sever static content from cookieless domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to serve my site's static content from newly created subdomain, but its not working. There is no option in the cPanel to make that subdomain cookieless. So i tried to use .htaccess to make it cookieless but still it didn't work for me. Here is my .htaccess code.

```
# Use Mod_deflate to compress static files
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch ".(js|css|ico|txt|htm|html|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

# Speed up caching
FileETag MTime Size

# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 366 days"

# Future Expires Headers
<filesmatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Sat, 27 Dec 2019 23:59:59 GMT"
</filesmatch>
```

The folder structure of my website is like this :

> main-dir/Images

My subdomain is pointing to Images/ . Now my images url will be new-subdomain/test.jpg.

Can someone tell me how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

All domains are cookieless until you try to send a cookie. If you try to serve images over a content delivery network like cloudflare, even on a cookieless domain, there will still be cookies getting sent out of your control. This can be disabled through cloudflare for paid plans. But if you have a domain like `mysite.com` and you have cookies that get served there, then all subdomains on this site will see all cookies for `mysite.com`. But if you're setting cookies from `www.mysite.com`, then this is treated as a subdomain which won't affect other adjacent subdomains like `subdomain.mysite.com` If you haven't set your site up like this in the past, then chances are you'll have some cookies floating around from things like session_start on your main site if you're not going through `www.` Alternatively create a new domain and point it at your server for this. Or serve the images through their ip address. Or just embrace what many people have, that sending cookies along with requests for assets aren't really worth the bother of optimizing. A fully optimized site will have no noticeable gain from this, and the concept of cookieless domains is quite overrated having little to no gain in the first place. It's even arguable that having a second domain set up for this can actually slow down your site due to the extra DNS lookup. So here's the options:

1. Enforce `www.` so you don't have any cookies sitting at `mysite.com` so you can make a subdomain cookieless
2. grab a new domain to be dedicated as a cookieless domain
3. use the ip address of the assets rather than the domain name, this is essentially another domain name as far as cookies are concerned. This is assuming you can gain access to the images through the domain name
4. Find a content delivery service out there which can do this for you
5. Realize the cons outweigh the pros and give up on trying to achieve a cookieless domain due to it being probably a waste of time better spent on higher priority things

Comment: my new subdomain is not working with www like www.subdomain.com. So it could be the issue?